# confused about the `copy` attribution of `numpy.astype`

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array

I am confused about the `copy` attribution of `numpy.astype`.
I check out the material in [link](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.astype.html),it said:

`By default, astype always returns a newly allocated array. If this is set to false, and the dtype, order, and subok requirements are satisfied, the input array is returned instead of a copy.`

it means that will change the original value of a ndarray object? 
Like:

```
x = np.array([1, 2, 2.5])
x.astype(int, copy=False)
```

but it seems that `x` still is the original value `array([ 1. ,  2. ,  2.5])` .
can anyone explain it? 
thank you very much~~

Comment: I've never used this attribute, and am having trouble thinking of a case where it would apply.  `x.astype(int, order='F', copy=False)` does return a view for a 1d int `x`.  For 1d order doesn't matter, and there's no change in dtype.

Comment: This `x` is dtype Float (because of the 2.5).  It can't be converted to `int` without change to the data.

Comment: This is too specialized of an attribute to worry about.  As @PaulPanzer notes, `view` is more useful.

Comment: I take that last comment back.  It is useful in a conditional dtype conversion - make a copy only if you must.

Comment: @AndrewGong thank you for the question ... it saves lot of memory space to use copy= False ...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What they mean is, if the original array exactly meets the specifiations you passed, i.e. has the correct dtype, majorness and is either not a subclass or you set the subok flag, then a copy will be avoided. The input array is never modified. In your example the dtypes don't match, so a new array is made regardless.

If you want the data not to be copied use view instead. This will if at all possible reinterpret the data buffer according to your specs.

```
x = np.array([1, 2, 2.5])
y = x.view(int)
y
#  array([4607182418800017408, 4611686018427387904, 4612811918334230528])
# y and x share the same data buffer:
y[...] = 0
x
# array([ 0.,  0.,  0.])
```

Comment: hello, why the dtypes don't match in my example?

Comment: @AndrewGong I'm pretty sure they have to be equal for `copy=False` to work. But your array has some `float` dtype and you are asking for `int`.

Comment: thank you. Now I have understood it. it seems that x and y must have the same or similiar data type like `int vs numpy.int64` or `float vs numpy.float64`

Answer (score 2):

> By default, astype always returns a newly allocated array. If this is set to false, and the dtype, order, and subok requirements are satisfied, the input array is returned instead of a copy.

Notice that the documentation you quoted doesn't mention `x` being modified at all - in fact, either a brand new array of the desired type is returned, or `x` is returned unmodified (if possible).

In your case, I believe `x` doesn't meet the `dtype` requirement. The documentation doesn't actually describe that requirement at all (so I can understand your confusion), but basically what it means is that the requested `dtype` (`int` in this case) must be able to fully represent all values of the original `dtype` (`float` in this case). Since you can't cram a `float` into an `int` without losing some information, you can't simply pretend that `x` is an `int` array.

As such, `astype` returns a new **copy** of `x`, with each value converted to `int`. It leaves `x` unmodified, so to get the converted array you need to check the value returned from `astype`:

```
x = np.array([1, 2, 2.5])
y = x.astype(int, copy=False)

print x # prints array([ 1. ,  2. ,  2.5]), since x hasn't been modified
print y # prints array([ 1. ,  2. ,  2]), since y is an integer-valued copy of x
```

Comment: in my case, why doesn't  x meet the dtype requirement?

Comment: @AndrewGong: the documentation doesn't really specify what is meant by the "`dtype requirement", but I've updated my answer to include my understanding of what is involved. Hope that helps.

Comment: it seems to x and y must have the same or similiar data type like `int vs numpy.int64` or `float vs numpy.float64`

Answer (score 1):

Here's a case where the `copy=False` works, returning the original array:

```
In [238]: x
Out[238]: array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
In [239]: y = x.astype(int,copy=False)
In [240]: id(x)
Out[240]: 2884971680
In [241]: id(y)
Out[241]: 2884971680     # same id

In [242]: z = x.astype(int)
In [243]: id(z)
Out[243]: 2812517656     # different id
```

In a sense this is a trivial case; but I wouldn't be surprised if every other case is just as trivial

```
In [244]: w = x.astype(int,order='F',copy=False)
In [245]: id(w)
Out[245]: 2884971680   # 1d array is both order C and F
```

In other words it returns the original array if required `dtype` and `order` don't require any changes.  That is if the original already meets the specs.

This isn't the same as a `view`.  A view is a new array (new id) but shared data buffer.  Rather it is more like the simpler Python assignment, `y = x`.

I may change my mind if someone can some up with a `copy=False` case that involves a change in `dtype`.

---

The same call, but with a different array will create a copy

```
In [249]: x1=np.arange(10.)      # float
In [250]: y1=x1.astype(int, copy=False)
In [251]: id(x1)
Out[251]: 2812517696
In [253]: id(y1)
Out[253]: 2812420768        # different id
In [254]: y1=x1.astype(float, copy=False)
In [255]: id(y1)
Out[255]: 2812517696
```

So you could use `copy=False` if you want, say a `int` dtype array, but without any loss in efficiency if the array is already `int`.

---

[Efficient way to cast scalars to numpy arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47429254/efficient-way-to-cast-scalars-to-numpy-arrays)

`np.array` with `copy=False` behaves in much the same way - returning the same array (id) if no transformation is required.

Comment: it seems that the original x will has the same id with y if x and y have the similiar data type like `int vs numpy.int64` or `float vs numpy.float64`.right?