# Efficient way to cast scalars to numpy arrays

Tags: python, numpy

When I write a function that accepts `ndarray` or `scalar` inputs

```
def foo(a):
    # does something to `a`
    #
    # a: `x` dimensional array or scalar
    # . . . 

    cast(a, x)
    # deal with `a` as if it is an `x`-d array after this
```

Is there an effeicint way yo write that `cast` function?  Basically what I'd want is a function that would cast:

- `a`, a `scalar` to `ndarray` with shape `((1,)*x)`
- `b`, an `ndarray` with `y<x` dims explicitly to shape `((1,) * (y-x) + b.shape)` (same as broadcasting)
- `c`, an `ndarray` with `x` dims is unaffected
- `d`, an `ndarray` with `y>x` dims throws an error
- do it all in-place (at least when starting with an array), to prevent double memory

it seems like this functionality is repeated so often in built-in functions that there should be some shortcut for it, but I'm not finding it.

I can do `a_ = np.array(a, ndmin = x, copy = False)` and then `assert len(a_.shape) == x)` , but that still makes a copy of arrays. (i.e. `a_.base is a` is `False`). Is there any way around this?

Comment: `np.array` takes a `copy` parameter.  We just explored that parameter in `astype`.  Functions like `atleast_3d` use `asarray` followed by some `newaxis` reshaping.  `np.expand_dims` might also give ideas.  Most of these actions make a view, not a copy.  Only `x.shape=...` changes shape 'in-place'.

Comment: `np.asarray` is `np.array` with `copy=False`.

Comment: @hpaulj `np.asarray` doesn't take a `ndmin` parameter though. And somehow `np.array(a, ndmin = x, copy = False)` still makes a copy of an array for me

Comment: Copy as in new id or new databuffer pointer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`asarray` returns the array itself (if starting with an array):

```
In [271]: x=np.arange(10)
In [272]: y = np.asarray(x)
In [273]: id(x)
Out[273]: 2812424128
In [274]: id(y)
Out[274]: 2812424128     # same id
```

`ndmin` produces a view:

```
In [276]: y = np.array(x, ndmin=2, copy=False)
In [277]: y
Out[277]: array([[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]])
In [278]: id(x)
Out[278]: 2812424128
In [279]: id(y)
Out[279]: 2811135704    # different id
In [281]: x.__array_interface__['data']
Out[281]: (188551320, False)
In [282]: y.__array_interface__['data']  # same databuffer
Out[282]: (188551320, False)
```

`ndmin` on an array of the right dim already:

```
In [286]: x = np.arange(9).reshape(3,3)
In [287]: y = np.array(x, ndmin=2, copy=False)
In [288]: id(x)
Out[288]: 2810813120
In [289]: id(y)
Out[289]: 2810813120     # same id
```

Similar discussion with `astype`,

[confused about the `copy` attribution of `numpy.astype`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47426375/confused-about-the-copy-attribution-of-numpy-astype)

Comment: Huh.  If I look at `.flags` and `.base` it seems like a new array, but the `.__array_interface__['data']` is the same?  That's a bit misleading.