# How do `ndarray.flags['OWNDATA']`, `ndarray.base`, `id(ndarray)` and `ndarray.__array_interface__['data']` differ?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I seem to have had an XY problem in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47429254/efficient-way-to-cast-scalars-to-numpy-arrays) question regarding how to tell if arrays share the same memory.  The ways I was checking were wrong and I'm not sure why.

Let's take a few examples

```
test = np.ones((3,3))
test2 = np.array(test, ndmin = 2, copy = False)
test3 = np.array(test, ndmin = 3, copy = False)
```

First, let's check if they're sharing memory using [`.base`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.base.html)

```
test2.base is test
False

test3.base is test
True
```

So it seems like `test3` is sharing data with `test` but `test2` isn't.  In fact `test2.base is None => True`, which I thought meant that it is seperate memory (i.e. a copy).

This impression is reinforced when I check with [`.flags`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.flags.html)

```
test2.flags['OWNDATA']
True

test3.flags['OWNDATA']
False
```

It seems again like only `test3` is sharing data, and `test2` is a copy.

But if I check with the `python` builtin [`id(...)`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#id)

```
id(test)
248896912

id(test2)
248896912

id(test3)
248897352
```

Now the `id` (which is supposedly the adress of the object in memory) of `test` and `test2` match but `test3` does not, which gives the exact opposite impression from the above methods.

And of course, both of those impressions are wrong because:

```
test.__array_interface__['data']
(209580688, False)

test2.__array_interface__['data']
(209580688, False)

test3.__array_interface__['data']
(209580688, False)
```

The actual [buffer addresses](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/arrays.interface.html) all match.  Indeed:

```
test[0,0] = 2

test, test2, test3

(array([[ 2.,  1.,  1.],
        [ 1.,  1.,  1.],
        [ 1.,  1.,  1.]]),  
array([[ 2.,  1.,  1.],
        [ 1.,  1.,  1.],
        [ 1.,  1.,  1.]]), 
array([[[ 2.,  1.,  1.],
         [ 1.,  1.,  1.],
         [ 1.,  1.,  1.]]]))
```

So if `ndarray.base`, `ndarray.flags['OWNDATA']`, and `id(ndarray)` don't actually tell me if memory is shared, what *are* they telling me?

Comment: And yeah, in the future I'll know to use [`np.shares_memory(test, test2)`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/arrays.interface.html) instead of any of these.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most of your confusion comes from the fact that `test2` **is** `test` and `test3` is a view of `test`.

#### `ndarray.base`

If an array is created as a view of another object, its `base` will point to the other object... or NumPy will follow that object's `base` chain and use the "root base". Sometimes one option, sometimes the other. There were a number of bugs and backward compatibility issues.

`test2` is not a view of `test`. `test2` **is** `test`. Its `base` is `None` because it's not a view.

`test3` is a view of `test`, and its `base` is set to `test`.

#### `ndarray.flags['OWNDATA']`

This flag is set if the array is a view. As previously stated, `test3` is a view and `test2` isn't, because `test2` **is** `test`.

#### `id`

`id` gives a numeric identifier for an object, guaranteed not to be the same as the identifier for any object whose lifetime overlaps with the first. This function does not care about NumPy and views; two different arrays with overlapping lifetimes will have different IDs, regardless of any view relationships.

`test2` is `test`, so of course it has the same ID as itself. `test3` is a different object with an overlapping lifetime, so it has a different ID.

#### `ndarray.__array_interface__['data']`

This is a tuple whose first element is an integer representing the memory address of the array's first element. (The second element is unimportant for the question.) `test`, `test2`, and `test3` all use the same data buffer, with their first elements at the same offset, so they give the same value here. However, two arrays that share memory won't always have the same value for this, because they might not have the same first element:

```
>>> import numpy
>>> x = numpy.arange(5)
>>> y = x[1:]
>>> z = x[:-1]
>>> x.__array_interface__['data']
(39692208L, False)
>>> y.__array_interface__['data']
(39692212L, False)
>>> z.__array_interface__['data']
(39692208L, False)
```

Comment: Yeah, just figured out `test2 is test == True` about a minute before you answered.  That makes everything make a bit more sense.  I forgot that arrays can share identity as well as memory.